# Python3 subprocess module: Passing an empty variable as a flag, is it possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to use `subprocess.call()` to execute a command-line program in python3.  I can get it to work fine, the following example executes with no problems:

```
subprocess.call(['add_phenotype.py', '-t', threads, '-s'])
```

However, I want to parse a file, and then based on what I find, run the command with different flags.  I can't figure out how to do this.

For example:

```
if zeroed_out_file:
    args = '-z'
else:
    args = ''

subprocess.call(['add_phenotype.py', '-t', threads, '-s', args])
```

fails if zeroed_out_file is FALSE.  The add_phenotype.py script exits immediately claiming that it doesn't recognize the arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument takes a list; just build that list dynamically:

```
args = ['add_phenotype.py', '-t', threads, '-s']
if zeroed_out_file:
    args.append('-z')

subprocess.call(args)
```

Appending additional command line switches is just a question of appending more values to `args`.

Comment: So simple and elegant, I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Thanks!